# Firefox: CORS Missing Allow Header

Tags: http, cors

My firefox is issuing an OPTIONS preflight request to my private backend to make a subsequent GET request with credentials.

The preflight request includes the headers

```
Origin http://localhost:9670
Access-Control-Request-Headers authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method GET
```

My server responds with

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:9670
Vary: Origin
```

According to the docs I found that should be fine.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Anyway, my firefox still states

> CORS Missing Allow Header

in the Transferred section of the Network tab in the Developer Console.

What is my server response missing?

Comment: Were you trying to run firefox with ng serve? This would be helpful 2 hours ago before finally finding this question/answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9670
Vary: Origin
```

the response to the preflight request must also contain

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

Otherwise, the access control check will fail and your browser won't send the actual (preflighted) request. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Are you implementing CORS from scratch in the backend? If so, why not use a ([good](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors)) CORS library, which you could configure to take care of all this for you?

Comment: I added those two headers and the preflight goes through now! Thanks.

Comment: I have to check about the cors library, that might be a good idea.

Comment: Even with Authorization header I still received the error. Turned out I needed `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,x-csrf-token')`. Basically check the content of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']` and see if you might need to add more to your response header. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers