# CORS only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, nginx

There was a CORS problem in the FireFox browser.

I have a project on microfrontends.

There is a Root project that collects fronts and the frontends themselves.

In the root project, headers for CORS for nginx are configured.

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
 if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
 }
```

The backend also has settings for CORS on the frontend.

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsPolicy, policy =>
    {
        policy
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
    });
});
```

There are no CORSerrors when working through Google Chrome, as well as through any other browser except Fox

When working through FireFox, there are no KORS headers.

[image]

What's wrong? help me please.

Comment: [Possible dupe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478852/firefox-cors-missing-allow-header)